# VBA If Else within For Next Loop

Tags: vba, for-loop, if-statement

I need a VBA If Else statement within a For Next loop

I have tried various arrangements of the statements, but they all error out.

```
Sub TestForIfElse()
   Dim Counter As Integer
   Dim i As Integer

   For i = 1 To 5

   Counter = i

   If Counter > 3 Then

        Exit For

    Else

    Next i   'ERROR NEXT WITHOUT FOR
End Sub
```

Run loop until test is met.

If Test not met, keep going

If test met, exit loop.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Replace `Else` with `End If`.

Comment: You need to include an `End If` if you want to use `If Else`. So you would use `If... Else... End If`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
Sub TestForIfElse()

   Dim Counter As Integer
   Dim i As Integer

   For i = 1 To 5

       Counter = i

       If Counter > 3 Then

            Exit For

       End If

   Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked beautifully.